# Ride request - map

Tags: uber-api

Where can I find a real example map from Uber API? I have set the request status to "accepted" but the embeded map URL is still an invalid 404-link.

I just want to see the map provided in the API-call: https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-map.

How can I find it?

Comment: Can you add example code of what you have attempted?

Comment: There is a known issue involving trip maps for requests made in the developer sandbox. We are working to resolve this and will update when we have more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i thought it was something like that.

Comment: @AndrewNoonan - Is there a place where we can see how the map will look like on the live server? Sohuld we load the map in an iFrame?

Answer (score 2):

For requests made in the sandbox a static map is returned when calling `GET /v1/requests/:request_id:/map`

For now that map will be the same for all sandbox requests and does not change as the sandbox request changes states. However, we are always improving the sandbox experience and the map will eventually be a more interactive map as the production ones are.

Comment: Yep when i wrote the question the api was not working on ubers end. thanks